# Finding and replacing text in multiple files within a folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Below is code that should let me select a folder, then find and replace periods in the word documents within the folder and replace them with a space.
I got the code to work, my computer crashed, and now I don't remember what I did, and I'm getting a 'user-defined type' error.
I'm not quite sure how to fix this.

I'm also trying to get this to work from excel (not just from word) so any help there would be appreciated.

```
Sub Step_1() 'select folder with raw files to clean up
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim objDocument As Word.Document

Dim intResult As Integer
Dim strPath As String
Dim arrFiles() As String
Dim i As Integer
'box will open where user can pick folder with raw files
intResult = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show
'checks if user has cancelled the dialog
If intResult <> 0 Then
'display folder search box
strPath = Application.FileDialog( _
msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1)
arrFiles() = GetAllFilePaths(strPath)
For i = LBound(arrFiles) To UBound(arrFiles)
Call ModifyFile(arrFiles(i))
Next i
End If
End Sub

Private Sub ModifyFile(ByVal strPath As String)
Dim wordApp As Word.Application
Dim objDocument As Word.Document
Set objDocument = wordApp.Documents.Open(strPath)
objDocument.Activate

For Each objDocument In strPath

With Selection.Find

.Text = "."
.Replacement.Text = " "
.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll


'there's a much longer list of things to replace

End With
objDocument.Close (True)

Next
Next

End Sub

Private Function GetAllFilePaths(ByVal strPath As String) _
As String()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim arrOutput() As String
ReDim arrOutput(1 To 1)
'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strPath)
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and
'prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
ReDim Preserve arrOutput(1 To i)
'print file path
arrOutput(i) = objFile.Path
i = i + 1
Next objFile
GetAllFilePaths = arrOutput
End Function
```

Comment: If you're running this in Excel then you need to add a reference to the Word object library in your Excel VB project.  Excel doesn't know what (eg) `Word.Application` is without that reference.  FYI you have unused items declared in `Step_1`, and in `ModifyFile` you don't create a new Word instance.

Comment: @TimWilliams I added the reference when i started the project. What do you mean by unused items declared? As far as ModifyFile, i'll create that. thanks.
The main issue was also coming from `For Each objDocument In strPath`

Comment: `For Each objDocument In strPath` makes no sense in that context - there is only one document and you already have it open.

Comment: @TimWilliams I deleted that, added the word instance... now the error im getting is on those `Next` at the end - it says "Next without For"... any clue about that?

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/34254-post4.html

Comment: If you delete the `For Each objDocument In strPath` then there's a matching `Next` which also needs removing.

Comment: @TimWilliams Removing the `Next Next` worked. thansk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cleaned up:

```vb
Sub ProcessFiles()
    
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As Word.document
    Dim strPath As String, allfiles As Collection, fPath

    strPath = GetFolderPath()
    If Len(strPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set allfiles = GetAllFiles(strPath, "*.doc*")
    If allfiles.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No Word files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Set wordApp = New Word.Application
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    'loop over found files
    For Each fPath In allfiles
        Debug.Print "Processing " & fPath
        Set wdDoc = wordApp.documents.Open(fPath)
        
        ReplaceDocContent wdDoc, ".", " "
        ReplaceDocContent wdDoc, ",", " "
        ReplaceDocContent wdDoc, "~", " "
        'etc.....
        
        wdDoc.Close True 'close and save changes
    Next fPath
    
    MsgBox "done"
End Sub

'replace text in a Word document with some other text
Private Sub ReplaceDocContent(doc As Word.document, findWhat, replaceWith)
    With doc.Range.Find
        .Text = findWhat
        .Replacement.Text = replaceWith
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
End Sub

'collect all files under folder `strPath` which match `pattern`
Private Function GetAllFiles(ByVal strPath As String, pattern As String) As Collection
    Dim objFile As Object, col As New Collection
    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject and list all files
    For Each objFile In CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(strPath).Files
        If objFile.Path Like pattern Then col.Add objFile.Path
    Next objFile
    Set GetAllFiles = col
End Function

'return selected folder path or empty string
Function GetFolderPath() As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show <> 0 Then GetFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
End Function
```